# Gradle test task execution mode different behavior between cmdline and intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am setting up an multiproject build with gradle. And Working with intellij IDEA IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2
Everything is OK

But I see a different behavior when running test task in cmdline or inside intellij run anything.

Suppose I have this project structure and all my test are ok, no code change added

```
+-- _Root
|   +-- SubProjectA
|   +-- SubProjectB
```

If I run `gradlew :SubProjectA:test --info` in cmdline i have the following result :

```
> Task :SubProjectA:test UP-TO-DATE
Caching disabled for task ':SubProjectA:test' because:
  Build cache is disabled
```

But if i run this command in intellij smart command or run anything (ctrl+ctrl shortcut)

I have the following result :

```
> Task :SubProjectA:test
Caching disabled for task ':SubProjectA:test' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':SubProjectA:test' is not up-to-date because:
  Task.upToDateWhen is false.
```

I can't figure out what intellij is doing to re-run test even if they are UP-TO-DATE. I have also checked that the same daemon is use when doing my experiment

Why is it saying **Task.upToDateWhen is false.** ?

Comment: Seems there is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-240111

Comment: I am pretty new to gradle and intellij so I doesn't suspect a bug. No impacting me now, it was just a curiosity question. Thx this seems the explanation